# How to change the tag of a docker image in J-Frog Artifactory?

Tags: docker, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

I tagged an image with name `repository-docker.artifactory.example.com/image_name/1.0` 
rather than `repository-docker.artifactory.example.com/image_name:1.0`

and this has saved the image in Artifactory as `repository-docker.artifactory.example.com/image_name/1.0:latest`

Any way I can change this .

Comment: You can't delete as in it's a permission policy in your company? Something is off because what you described should have saved the image under `repository-docker.artifactory.example.com/image_name/1.0/latest`

Comment: Sorry I have edited the wrong part , and due to permission policies I cant use the delete API.@Hiruma

Comment: In that case you have no choice but to retag your image, push it and then reach out to an admin explaining that deleting the tag is fine because there is another tag for the same layers and it's just a tidying up task.

Comment: oh thanks for the help @Hiruma